# How to find out the regions a classifier performs well in machine learning?

Tags: r, machine-learning

I need to find out the regions (could be more than 1) where a classifier performs well on training data. I need to somehow store those regions and for two or more classifiers find out the overlaps of regions of different classifiers. How can I implement this in R or any other libraries? The dataset will definitely be multidimensional.

Comment: What classifier do you use? It certainly depends on this, for example decision trees have this capability out of the box.

Comment: Also you might want to read on semiparametric regression.

Comment: My problem is for general case. The classifier can be of any type. It's a vital part of my thesis. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a large amount of testing data, enough to cover a meaningful amount of your IV space.
2. Apply your classifier to the testing data. Evaluate it, using [your favorite error measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352).
3. Use a regression method to learn how the error of your classifier depends on the input IVs.

Essentially, you would be using a two-step ML procedure, where the second step would be to learn how well the the first step performs.

I recommend that you don't use *training* data, but *test* data here. Otherwise you will be very likely to overfit.